# jQuery plus minus toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to implement plus/minus icons in a the datagrid using jQuery. On expand, minus icon is coming but on collapse the plus icon is not coming back.

Here is the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/3fwyf/10/

Can anyone please look into the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
$('.minus').show();
$('.add').hide();
```

with

```
$('.minus').toggle();
$('.add').toggle();
```

Answer (score 8):

As Sandeepan Nath's answer, but in one line.

Replace

```
$('.minus').show();
$('.add').hide();
```

With

```
$('.minus, .add').toggle();
```